# Get activity from Back Stack keeping history, instead of creating new one

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I'm trying to do something like this:

I have some activities in task:

A->B->C

and from C i want to call instance of B from stack and keep current history. So the wondered result looks like this:

A->B->C->B

where B and B is the same instances, but with possibility to navigate back with Back button.

Is it possible?

May be duped:
[Android task history stack: can have "duplicate activities"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641072/android-task-history-stack-can-have-duplicate-activities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by realising my own Back Stack. Main idea was to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_BRING_TO_TOP for indicating my singleton acivities.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Android doesn't support this case.

You can have either:

A->B->C->B (where B are both activities of the same class, but which are two different objects)

pr

A->C->B (where B is brought to the front).

However, I think you can build something on your own. If you will serialize the state of B on onPause() and deserialize it on onCreate() and onResume(), you may have two B's in the stack (which will be separate objects), but they still have the same state (as example all members).